# How can I send an array of 17 bytes over serial port using python?

Tags: python, network-programming, serial-port, serial-communication

This what I have to send `85, 170, 81,42,17,0,2,21,255,255,66,11,52,54,0,97,168`.
I have tried using `bytearray()` but it will send `bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03')`, and I only want 17 bytes to be sent.

Comment: You're looking for the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module: `struct.pack('B' * len(lst), *lst)`.

Comment: This is what i m getting: lst=[10,100,200]
>>> f=struct.pack('B'*len(lst),*lst)
>>> f
'\nd\xc8'